# Web scraping errors while coding for word-frequency code

Tags: python

I am doing a web **scraping** project and I am new to python please help me on the basis of this code.

```
 word_frequency = {}
        for token in k:
                if token not in word_frequency.keys():
                    word_frequency[token] = 
                else:
                    word_frequency[token] += 
        max_frequency = max(word_frequency.values)
        max_frequency
        word_highest = nlargest(100, word_frequency,key = word_frequency.get)
        word_highest
    #plotting line graph
    keys = word_frequency.keys()
    values = word_frequency.values()
    
    keys = list(keys)[:21] #first 20 most frequent words
    values = list(values)[:21]# frequency of first 20 most frequent words
    
    plt.plot(keys, values)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 80)
    plt.xlabel('Words')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.title('Word Frequency')
    plt.show()
```

what should i do?
my syntax errors are:

```
     NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-2-1783d4bb5793> in <module>()
              2 #determining up the frequency
              3 word_frequency = {}
        ----> 4 for token in k:
              5         if token not in word_frequency.keys():
              6             word_frequency[token] = 1# if word occured only once put value as 1
        
        NameError: name 'k' is not defined
        TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-5-293f321e384b> in <module>()
              1 # finding the maximum frequency
        ----> 2 max_frequency = max(word_frequency.values)
              3 max_frequency
        
        TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
        NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-4-29ca2b9912cd> in <module>()
              1 # Accesing first 100 words with largest frequency
        ----> 2 word_highest = nlargest(100, word_frequency,key = word_frequency.get)
              3 word_highest
        
        NameError: name 'nlargest' is not defined
        NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-6-06cf5f0bf91a> in <module>()
              6 values = list(values)[:21]# frequency of first 20 most frequent words
              7 
        ----> 8 plt.plot(keys, values)
              9 plt.xticks(rotation = 80)
             10 plt.xlabel('Words')
        
        NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

please help me, what shall I do?

Comment: Start with insuring that you have all necessary `import` statements and that any variable you use gets appropriate value ***before*** they are actually used.

Comment: I don't see any web scraping errors here. Could you explain more about your problem ?

Comment: I suggest working through some python tutorials first.